# Suppress Xcode's "Full Screen Behavior" warning

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, osx-lion

How can I suppress Xcode's "Full Screen Behavior on Mac OS X prior to 10.7" warning that occurs in my xib files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in Xcode 4.2.

Comment: It's an issue again in 4.6!!

Comment: For anyone who comes to this, there is a SDK version for the project, and another one for the xib file. Choose "Builds for OS X 10.7 and later".

Answer (score 0):

In **Inspector**, on the **Interface Builder Document** tab, change the deployment version to **Project SDK Version (Mac OS X 10.7)** or **Mac OS X 10.7**.

Comment: Both files in question are already set to Project SDK Version (Mac OS X 10.7).

Answer (score 0):

Change your Target's Base SDK to 10.7 (Build Settings tab in the Project Navigator inspector).

Comment: What is your Deployment target and how do you set a Full Screen feature (in IB or in a code)?

Comment: My deployment target is 10.5, but the warnings do not go away even if I change it to 10.7, and I use the full screen behavior popup in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Running Xcode 5 I still encounter this. There is a SDK version for the project, and another one for the xib file. Choose "Builds for OS X 10.7 and later" and you should be good to go.